# Java check Redis memory usage

Tags: java, memory, redis

I needs Java code to monitor Redis's memory usage because Redis stores all data into RAM and it will crash if the memory is full.

It looks like Redis uses the whole OS memory, so if I use "Runtime" method in Java, it is no correct because it only counts the memory in JVM.

Is there any Java method to monitor the whole OS system's memory usage or these is some magic Redis method?

Answer (score 3):

You could make periodic requests to redis, sending an [`INFO`](http://redis.io/commands/info) command, and parse the result to get the value of `used_memory`, which is the number of bytes allocated by Redis memory allocator.

**update:** Redis won't crash, it will swap - and so its performances will dramatically fall. You may detect swapping by comparing used_memory_rss to used_memory. used_memory_rss much greater than used_memory means swapping occured. But before that you can be wanted swapping will occur if used_memory is just below the total memory available for Redis.

If you are using redis as a cache, you may limit its memory consumption by adding these lines in the config file :

```
maxmemory 2mb 
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

In this example it will be limited to 2 Mb.

**update**
`maxmemory` will prevent new write operations when the limit is reached, and respond with an error; and it will start to delete keys according to the LRU policy, which is appropriated for a cache.

Comment: OK. But I cannot find any java redis api about sending "info" command to redis.

Comment: Did you find any java redit api ? @user3019299